# Comparing datatable names with enum

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an enum of datatable names and i am trying to loop through a datatable.. and remove all the ones where they are not equal

So if the datatable name is not equal to any of the enums, remove it

My enum is named DAL.eDataBaseQuestions
And datatable is named dt as DAL.GetTable

This is what i have done so far

```
Dim dt As DataTable = DAL.GetTable
        Dim str1 As String
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            str1 = dc.ColumnName.ToString
            'Response.Write(str1 & ", ")

            For Each i As str1 In System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(DAL.eDataBaseQuestions)

            Next

        Next
```

The first foreach can get the column names, but I am not sure how to compare them with the enum text values.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your question does really make sense as it is.  Try being clear.  You say that you have datatable names but you want to compare with columns???  Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want to remove the `DataColumns` from the `DataTable` if there names don't match a field in your `Enum`?  Or do you maybe mean that you actually want to remove `DataRows` if they don't contain a value that matches a field in your `Enum`?

Comment: Sorry, i am trying to remove the columns via (dt.columns.remove..) so when i export it will only have the columns in the enum. Essentially, i want to dt.columns.remove everything that is not in my enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that column names are `Strings`, you'd need to use `GetNames` rather than `GetValues`.  Given that you are talking about removing items from a collection, you need to use a `For` loop and count backwards:

```
Dim names = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(SomeEnum))

For i = table.Columns.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim column As DataColumn = table.Columns(i)

    If Not names.Contains(column.ColumnName) Then
        table.Columns.Remove(column)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You can't use a For Each loop because you are messing with the collection you are iterating by remove items from it. You have to go backwards because otherwise your indexes will change.